# I want to make a simple timer using JavaScript for A-FRAME

Tags: javascript, html, aframe

I want to make a script for a timer that lasts 15 minutes and when it ends it makes an entity invisible. How can I code it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post some code so we can see where you're starting from.

Comment: If any of these answers helped you, show some gratitude by checking the answer that solved it for you. You will get some good karma points.

Answer (score 1):

You make an object invisible by calling it with `setAttribute('material', 'opacity', 0)`

place that call inside of a setTimeout( function( // select the entity, set its opacity), timeInMilliseconds)

[glitch here](https://glitch.com/~timer-set-opacity)

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use the set timeout function.

```
i = document.GetElementById(“id”)

function timer() {
setTimeout(function(){i.style.visibility = “hidden”;}, 900000)
//If you want the timer to start automatically
timer();
```